# How do I make Python open a Youtube video?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm building a simple GUI in python with some text and a button inside.
I want to click on that button and open a youtube video.

How would I do that? Mouse event? is there some kind of onclick function like in javascript?

here is my code

```
from tkinter import*

window = Tk()
window.title("DdP Program")
window.geometry("300x100")

def onClick(event):

label = Label(text="some text")
label.pack()

labelOne = Label(text="A little bit more text")
labelOne.pack()

click = Button(text = "Clica Aqui!", command = onClick)
click.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you missing some indents in the `def`?

Comment: You're already using the `command` argument, so I think you already know how to do things in response to mouse clicks. So the question isn't "how do I open a youtube video in response to a mouse click?", it's "How do I make Python open a Youtube video?". In fact, this has nothing to do with Tkinter at all.

Comment: Are you expecting it to open in your GUI, or are you asking how to open it in a browser?

Comment: @Kevin you are right. I edited the title of the question so its more clear what i'm looking for. So in this case I would have to write a fuction (in this case will be called onClick) that will open a youtube video when the button is pressed. is there any specific terminology i should be using?

Comment: @Kevin. As with so many similar cases, this appears to be a question where code is posted in a poor attempt to avoid "there is no code posted" close votes. The problem is that there is no *relevant* code.

Comment: @BryanOakley opening youtube on a new browser window

Comment: @Miguel. You should make an attempt to do the thing you are asking about first, so that *you* have a clear idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have a clear idea of what I want to do. I simply don't know how to put that into code. I'm not familiar with python language and im just trying to work it out. This is not some university exercise or homework. Im just trying to learn a bit by myself. Would apreciate some guidelines and/or advice instead of being told that i'm only posting poor attempts to avoid close posts.

Comment: @Miguel. That sounds quite reasonable. Keep in mind that even if your post is closed, you can always vote to reopen after editing it. My advice would be to post relevant code: the code here is completely irrelevant to your actual problem. Do some research. Your problem is a fairly common one and Google is most definitely your friend. If everything works out, you don't need a question here at all. If you legitimately can't get anything to work, ask a question showing what you tried and explaining why it didn't work, and people will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module from standard library

```
import webbrowser
url = "http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html"
webbrowser.open(url,new=1)
```

so

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("DdP Program")
window.geometry("300x100")


def onClick(x):
    webbrowser.open(x,new=1)


label = Label(text="some text")
label.pack()

labelOne = Label(text="A little bit more text")
labelOne.pack()


url = "http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html"

click = Button(text="Clica Aqui!", command=lambda: onClick(url))
click.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

We need to give argument but we can't use `command=onClick(url)` because it will invoke the function instantly (not when the button clicked) and assign its value to command so we can wrap the Onclick function with lambda function like this `command=lambda: onClick(url)`. Lambda function will be invoked when button clicked and it will invoke onClick function with its argument

Comment: Thank you for answer. I managed to get there by my self after a while and this was the exact solution i got to. And this is the kind of answer I was looking for when i made the question along with an explanation, instead of other people posting comments such as "this is a poor code attemp to avoid no code posted". Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please could you explain how this code presented above opens a Youtube video? My understanding ends where there is simply no Youtube video referenced, e.g. in the URL or wherever. (I am trying to build a small Python tool to start Youtube videos, too.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann sorry for the late answer, i wasnt here for a long time.
"url" variable must have a yotube video link but looks like i didnt write here.
"click = Button(text="Clica Aqui!", command=lambda: onClick(url))" here we assigned onClick funtion to Button, when Button pressed onClick is called which passes the url to "webbrowser.open(x,new=1)" in its definiton and it opens the url in a browser